# Linq How to combine two List's columns

Tags: c#, linq, list

Please Help me in the following...
I have two list objects as follows:

```
list1:
ID  col1
--------
1   A
1   B
1   C

list2:
ID  col2
--------
1   D
1   E 
1   F

Now I want:
ID  col1  col2
---------------
1    A     D
1    B     E
1    C     F
```

So basically column1 then column 2 from list1 then column 3 from list 2. Column1 is common.
Please note that the number of rows may not be always same.. in that case it will be null.

I really really need this solution in Linq. Thanks.

Comment: 1) what is a type of a list item? 2) is this LINQ-to-Objects?

Comment: You can use a Linq Join: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Comment: @sll Yes it is Linq-to-Objects

Comment: @Infotekka Linq Join gives me Cross Join, which is not what I want.. you can say I want inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Class> list1 = new List<Class>();
List<Class> list2 = new List<Class>();

// Add classes to lists...

list1.AddRange(list2);

// Order merged list...

list1.OrderByDescending(o => o.col1).ThenBy(o => o.col2);
```

Trying to understand...

```
Dictionary<Int32, Class[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<Int32, Class[]>();

list2.Reverse();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
    dictionary[i] = new Class[2] { list1[i], list2[i] };
```

Comment: I tried the above, but it just added list2 at the bottom. I got only two columns where i was supposed to get 3 columns

Comment: The problem is that your question is bad posed. We can't understand if you want a single list result or to keep different lists ordered in different ways. You provide no code. You provide no specs.

Comment: @Zarathos I want the two lists combined in one single list.

Comment: Ok and you need to intersect them? To sort them separately? To add to the top? To shuffle? It's still not too clear :S

Comment: @Zarathos Thank you for your patience :). Sorting, shuffle is not my concern. Think of a database table, there is a common column in two tables. I want the common column then the rest of the columns from the two tables in the result. The common column is not unique but has the same value in both tables, so join gives me cross join in linq. Did that make any sense?

Comment: Mhhh... still not that clear... anyway, a List is a straightforward container... items are "stacked" inside like into an Array. So what's wrong with adding a list to the bottom of another one and then ordering it if you want a single List result? Maybe you have to use a Dictionary<Class, Class> instead...

Comment: if i add it at the bottom i will still have 2 dimensional array... i want two two dimensional array combined in one three dimensional array. the two two dimensional array have a common value.

Comment: So you can use a Dictionary.

Comment: Could you give me an example of that in Linq. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really don´t understand why was hard for get clear the question, he only want have two array combined in one (still i don't know why in the aswers of the web you only find Concat,AddRange or Union. Wrong Answers For this Question):

I solve it with Zip:

```
       var result = list1.Zip(list2,(first,second)=>new  {entrada=first,salida=second});
```

Now You Can do Something like this:

```
       var union=result.Select(x=> new {x.entrada, x.salida, horas = int.Parse((DateTime.Parse(x.salida).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(x.entrada))).Hours.ToString()) });
```